# Разреженный массив

Tags: c++, массивы, перегрузка-операторов

Пытаюсь реализовать разряженный массив и перегрузить для него оператор []. Читал, что можно перегрузить оператор на чтение и на запись (если это так, то как это сделать?)
В общем хочу сделать следующее: 
Оператор [] для этого случая: `cout<<array[0]<<endl;` тут только на вывод
И оператор [] для этого случая: `array[0] = 1;` Тут оператор возвращает значение, которое можно и изменить и вывести
Для каждого случая хочу реализовать отдельную логику
Изменил на это:

```
int operator[](int index) const {
    return dataArray[index];
}

int& operator[](int index)  {
    return dataArray[index];
}
```

Вызов в main:

```
cout << sp[0] << endl;

sp[0] = 1;
```

Comment: При прохождении отладчиком  по коду, в первом и во втором случае вызывается int& operator[](int index)

Comment: `const` версия будет вызвана только для `const` обьекта

Comment: То есть так, как я хочу, перегрузить не получиться?

Comment: @EOF согласен. Похоже. надо прокси добавлять.

Comment: @Harry Ну или явно приводить к ссылке на `const` с помощью `const_cast`, где нужно.

Comment: @EOF Ну, тогда уж проще дописать другой оператор - типа для записи `a(1)`, для чтения `a[2]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то ничего лучше, чем вот такая [жуть](https://ideone.com/EmviR6), в голову не приходит. И не писал бы, но раз уж в комментариях сказал А, надо говорить и Б...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Array
{

    struct proxy
    {
        int operator =(int v)
        {
            m[s] = v;
            return v;
        }

        operator int()
        {
            if (m.count(s)) return m[s];
            return 0;
        }

        proxy(Array*a, size_t s):m(a->m),s(s){}
        map<size_t,int> &m;
        size_t s;
    };
public:
    Array() = default;

    proxy operator[](size_t s)
    {
        return proxy(this,s);
    }

    size_t count() { return m.size(); }

private:
    map<size_t,int> m;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Array a;
    a[5] = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n" << a.count() << endl;
}
```

Самому не нравится, так что, надеюсь, кто-то придумает что получше...

Comment: Я подробно код не разбирал, может там реально жуть, но это вообще-то вполне стандартный способ сделать подобное. То есть если в данном случае оператор [] присутствует условно в правой стороне присвоения, то пусть прокся ведёт себя будто значение, а если в левой, то она уже честно проксит, производя дополнительные действия... И именно так и следует реализовывать логику работы с разрежёнными массивами, врятли есть что-то более удачное...